# Python, NumPy: Neural network tutorial, ValueError: shapes not aligned

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to code a neural network with 3 input nodes, a hidden layer with 4 nodes, and 1 output node. (This will change in the final version, so I've turned them into variables.) Even though I've compared my code to the tutorials, and I can't see anything wrong with it, when I try to run it, it gives me a ValueError saying that it can't dot-multiply these arrays.

As this is my first project using NumPy, I'm at a loss as to what I'm supposed to do.

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import math

# neurons
n_in = 3
n_hidden = 4
n_out = 1
batchsize = 60

def sigmoid(x, deriv=False):
    if deriv:
        return x*(1-x)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def error(expected, actual):
    rawError = expected - actual
    for cell in rawError:
        cell = cell * cell
    return rawError

# input data
X = np.array([
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1]
])

# answer data
Y = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0]).T

np.random.seed(0)

# synapses
syn0 = 2 * np.random.random((n_in, n_hidden)) - 1
syn1 = 2 * np.random.random((n_hidden, n_out)) - 1

# train
for j in range(60000):
    # feed forward to hidden
    l1 = sigmoid(np.dot(X, syn0))
    # feed forward to out
    l2 = sigmoid(np.dot(l1, syn1))
    # calculate error in new array
    l2_error = error(Y, l2)
    if j % 10000 == 9999:
        print(np.sum(l2_error))

    # gradient descent:
    # multiply the error by the input, then the gradient of sigmoid
    l2_nudge = l2_error * sigmoid(l2, deriv=True)
    l1_nudge = l2_nudge.dot(syn1.T) * sigmoid(l1, deriv=True)
    syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_nudge)
    syn0 += l0.T.dot(l1_nudge)
print(l2)
```

I expected the program to at least run, but it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neural-network.py", line 68, in <module>
    l1_nudge = l2_nudge.dot(syn1.T) * sigmoid(l1, deriv=True)
ValueError: shapes (4,4) and (1,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue: I was doing the dot product for `l1_error` backwards!

```
l1_error = np.dot(l2_nudge, syn1.T)
```